# How to load image from redirecting url in android

Tags: android, imageview, redirect, picasso

Hi i am facing this problem
I am getting a url from RESTCall
the url is http://hck.re/kWWxUI
but it redirects to https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/afreen2ac5a33.jpg when i checked in browser
How can i load this image into my imageView I already know how to load an image from Picasso into an imageView. Any help would be appreciated

> Edit: I have added this code

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
            .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
            .build();

    picasso.load(music.getUrl())
            .fit()
            .into(holder.cover_image);
```

Sill no luck

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/463#issuecomment-39474692

Comment: @CommonsWare i changed http to https still the url is getting redirected

Comment: @CommonsWare how can i load image from http://hck.re/kWWxUI using Picasso or any other library ?

Comment: AFAIK, Picasso relies on the underlying HTTP transport to handle redirects. Either add OkHttp to your build (as was suggested in the GitHub issue comment that I linked to), or [configure `HttpURLConnection` to follow redirects](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)), bearing in mind that the latter would affect all of your uses of `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have modified http stack also but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

CustomPicasso.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Hrishikesh Kadam on 19/12/2017
 */

public class CustomPicasso {

    private static String LOG_TAG = CustomPicasso.class.getSimpleName();
    private static boolean hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet;

    public static Picasso with(Context context) {

        if (hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet)
            return Picasso.with(context);

        try {
            Picasso.setSingletonInstance(null);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Default singleton instance already present" +
                    " so CustomPicasso singleton cannot be set. Use CustomPicasso.getNewInstance() now.");
            return Picasso.with(context);
        }

        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();

        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> CustomPicasso singleton set to Picasso singleton." +
                " In case if you need Picasso singleton in future then use Picasso.Builder()");
        hasCustomPicassoSingletonInstanceSet = true;

        return picasso;
    }

    public static Picasso getNewInstance(Context context) {

        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "-> Do not forget to call customPicasso.shutdown()" +
                " to avoid memory leak");

        return new Picasso.Builder(context).
                downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context))
                .build();
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
android {

    ...

}

dependencies {

    ...

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
}
```

Usage -

```
CustomPicasso.with(context)
    .load("http://hck.re/kWWxUI")
    .into(imageView);
```

For latest revisions check CustomPicasso gist - https://gist.github.com/hrishikesh-kadam/09cef31c736de088313f1a102f5ed3a3